# BottomSheet with Viewpager giving arrayindex out of bound

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an app where I have to make a bottom sheet with viewpager for tabs.

When I add data to my dataprovider class, and after three to four swipes, it throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I've searched a solution for this issue on Stack Overflow, but I can't still figure out what I'm doing wrong.

BottomSheet.java

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_booking,null,false);
        bottomsheet_pager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.bottomsheet_pager);
        adapter = new BottomSheet_ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        bottomsheet_pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        bottom_tablyout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_tablyout);
        bottom_tablyout.setupWithViewPager(bottomsheet_pager);
        liquer_data_providers = new ArrayList<>();


        return view;
    }
```

ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
public class BottomSheet_ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    //Liquer_Data_Provider provider = new Liquer_Data_Provider();
    ArrayList<Liquer_Data_Provider> providers =  new ArrayList<>();

    public BottomSheet_ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Bottom_Viewpager_Fragment fragment = new Bottom_Viewpager_Fragment();
        position = position+1;
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("mesasge","Fragment :"+position);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        position = position+1;
        return "Fragment"+position;
    }
}
```

and BottomViewPagerFragment.java

```
public class Bottom_Viewpager_Fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    View view;
    AppCompatImageView bottle_checked1;
    CustomTextView bottle_text1,beerprice1;
    private boolean isClicked = true;
    private String[] liquertype = {"Top Selling","Wine","Vodka","Whisky","Rum"};
    private String[] liquerdata=  {"Cointreau","Zoladkowa","Disaramo","Amarula","Kohla"};
    private int[] price = {20,30,40,50,60};
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    Liquer_Data_Provider liquer_data_provider;
    ArrayList<Liquer_Data_Provider> liquer_data_providers;

    public Bottom_Viewpager_Fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom__viewpager_, container, false);
        bottle_checked1 = (AppCompatImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.bottle_checked1);
        bottle_text1 = (CustomTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.bottle_text1);
        beerprice1 = (CustomTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.beerprice1);
        liquer_data_providers = new ArrayList<>();

        for(String data:liquerdata) {
            liquer_data_provider = new Liquer_Data_Provider(liquertype[i],data,price[j]);
            i++;
            j++;
            liquer_data_providers.add(liquer_data_provider);
            bottle_text1.setText(liquer_data_provider.getGlass_name());
            beerprice1.setText(Integer.toString(liquer_data_provider.getPrice()));
        }

        bottle_text1.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (isClicked) {
            bottle_checked1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            isClicked  = false;
        } else {
            bottle_checked1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            isClicked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

and Logcat details

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.ct.listrtrial, PID: 6071
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5
    at com.ct.listrtrial.fragments.Bottom_Viewpager_Fragment.onCreateView(Bottom_Viewpager_Fragment.java:47)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2346)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1428)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:792)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2215)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:649)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1238)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1086)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:267)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private String[] liquertype = {"Top Selling","Wine","Vodka","Whisky","Rum"};
private String[] liquerdata=  {"Cointreau","Zoladkowa","Disaramo","Amarula","Kohla"};
```

should be same size of both array **liquertype** and **liquerdata**.

you got exception because liquertype size has 6 and liquerdata size has 5.

```
for(String data:liquerdata) {
            liquer_data_provider = new Liquer_Data_Provider(liquertype[i],data,price[j]);
...
..
.
```

Comment: check again `liquertype = {"Top Selling","Wine","Vodka","Whisky","Rum"};` and `liquerdata=  {"Cointreau","Zoladkowa","Disaramo","Amarula","Kohla"};` both have 5 data in array

Comment: but @vijay where do you see liquer type has 6 data both have 5

Comment: sorry @Smith, please show me  the line `Bottom_Viewpager_Fragment.java:47`

Comment: @Vijay liquer_data_provider = new Liquer_Data_Provider(liquertype[i],data,price[j]);  this is the line causing error

Comment: @Smith, Once you try **i** and **j** initialize in `onCreateView()` above for loop.

Comment: @Vijay index exception is gone but now only one data is showing instead of 5